# Cannot find PostGis address_standardizer extension

Tags: postgis-2.2

I installed postgres and postgis using the enterprise db standard installer for osx. everything feels normal and works great!

But I cannot find any sign of the address_standardizer extension. I'm guessing that EDB didn't get it integrated into the PostGis 2.2 package that shows up in their stackbuilder.

And for sure, there's no way to diagnose the problem using the PostGis documentation that sends you from Ch 13, to 2.8.3 and then 2.7 and then Ch 13. and..

If I download Postgis source then I have to worry about where is make and all the mysteries of bash and the search path and I'll be up for weeks trying to unwind tall tales about the glory of 39 million ways to something that can't be done one way.

And if i succeed in building it, then the first page of the PostGis 2.2 site says you can't install twice. So how do I get the address_standardizer extension into my postgres lib folder so I can load it up and get back to work?

I've got the whole of the USA in tiger_data, but it's useless if I have to write a standardizer. Should I call KyngChaos and ask if he can email me the .so file?

Comment: did you try CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer SCHEMA public VERSION "2.2.2";

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I just rediscovered this comment on the PostGIS 2.2 page:

The OSX PostgreSQL/Stackbuilder combination from EnterpriseDB has had mixed reliability. Avoid.

Ok, I don't want to rewind everthing. And I definitely did not enjoy the results of Postgres.app.

So I'm going to try to install postgis from homebrew and find out where I'm going after that.